# how do I change text in a label with swift?

Tags: uilabel, swift

I'm trying to change the text on a label in a simple iOS app.

The idea is to write a message in a textField and have it change the label once I press a button.

the **objective-c** code states the following:

```
[self.simpleLabel setText:message]
```

simpleLabel: is associated with the `UILabel`
`setText:` is the method
message: is a variable set in a previous line

How would I write this in swift?

I tried combing through the Apple documentation but came up with nothing.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/text

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Swift uses the same cocoa-touch API. You can call all the same methods, but they will use Swift's syntax. In this example you can do something like this:

```
self.simpleLabel.text = "message"
```

Note the setText method isn't available. Setting the label's text with = will automatically call the setter in swift.

Comment: I tried similar combinations but none of them worked. 
thanks!

Comment: Where do I specify the label ID "simpleLabel"?

Comment: simpleLabel is the name he used in his example. Use whatever variable you have for your label in place of it

Answer (score 18):

**swift solution**

```
yourlabel.text = yourvariable
```

or  self is use for when you are in async {brackets} or in some Extension

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
    self.yourlabel.text = "typestring"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use a simple formula:
**WHO.WHAT = VALUE**

where,

**WHO** is the element in the storyboard you want to make changes to for eg. label

**WHAT** is the property of that element you wish to change for eg. text

**VALUE** is the change that you wish to be displayed

for eg. if I want to change the text from *story text* to *You see a fork in the road* in the label as shown in [screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVIqE.png)

In this case, our **WHO** is the label (element in the storyboard), **WHAT** is the text (property of element) and **VALUE** will be *You see a fork in the road*

so our final code will be as follows: [Final code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cgjL.png)

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVIqE.png) changes to [screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSDss.png) once the above code is executed.

I hope this solution helps you solve your issue. Thank you!